# Why can't insert the image with listitem in Xul

Tags: xul

I have tried many methods to insert the image with listitem

but there is not any error with that, I still can't show my image

please help

Comment: Did you managed to make it work?

Comment: yes it works, but listitem don't insert the image?

Comment: No. Listboxes can't contain images. If you want to have images you should use richlistbox instead. If you feel that this answered your question, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says on the documentation for [Listbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/listbox),:

> If you wish to create a list with variable height rows, or with
>   non-text content, you should instead use the [richlistbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/richlistbox) element:

```
<richlistbox>
    <richlistitem>
        <description>A XUL Description!</description>
    </richlistitem>
    <richlistitem>
        <image src="chrome://myExt/content/images/myImage.png"/>
    </richlistitem>
</richlistbox>
```